# Pandas change range into int

Tags: python, pandas, string, parsing, data-science

In my `df` I have a  `salary_range` column, which contains ranges like `100 000 - 150 000`. I'd like to modify this column so it would take the first value as an int. So in this example I'd like to change `"100 000 - 150 000`(string) to `100000`(int). Unfortunatelly `salary_range` is full of `NaN`, and I don't really know how to use if/where statements in pandas.
I tried doing something like this: `df['salary_range'] = np.where(df['salary_range']!='NaN',)` but I don't know what should I write as the second argument of `np.where`. Obviously I can't just use `str(salary_range)`, so I don't know how to do it.

Comment: could you show your code?

Comment: Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow — we expect questions here to relate to *specific* programming problems — but we will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us [what you've tried](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and where you are stuck. This will also help us answer your question better.

Comment: I edited my question @xszym

Answer (score 0):

You first need to take the subset where the value is not NaN. This can be done using the following code.

```
pd.isna(df['salary_range'])
```

The above function will return a series containing True/False values. Now you can select the non-NaN rows using the following code.

```
df[pd.isna(df['salary_range'])]
```

Next you will need to parse the entries of this subset, which can be done in many ways, one of which can be the following.

```
df[pd.isna(df['salary_range'])]['salary_range'] = df[pd.isna(df['salary_range'])]['salary_range'].str.split(' ')[0].replace(' ', '').astype(int)
```

This will only change the rows, where the column is not null. Since you did not include the code, I can't help much without knowing more about the context. Hope this helps.